getStaticProps - No Current User (AWS AppSync, Next.js)
I am using AWS Amplify with AppSync and DynamoDB. Here is my simple API call using getStaticProps.
import React from 'react';
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { listCompanies } from '../graphql/queries';

export default function Test({ companyList }) {
  return (
      <ul>
        {companyList.map(company => (
          <li key={company.id}>{company.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const queryData = await API.graphql({
    query: listCompanies,
    variables: {
      type: 'info',
    },
  });
  const companyList = queryData.data.listCompanies.items;

  return {
    props: {
      companyList,
    },
  };
}

It gives the error Error: No current user
My current schema.graphql auth rules (I believe it is related to auth at the server), but I have already given public read access so I dont know why it even needs an authenticated user, if this is the issue.

input AMPLIFY {
  globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public }
} # FOR TESTING ONLY!
type Item
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "sub", operations: [create, update, delete] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
    ]
  )

